# Bash's function will invoke command with quoted argument broken down?

Tags: bash, bash-function

Let's say I have a function in Bash:

```
function ll {
    command ls -l $*
}
```

so it is to make `ll` works like `ls -l`.  Most of the cases, it will work, but

```
ls -l "ha ha"
```

can work for the file with name `ha ha`, but

```
ll "ha ha"
```

will fail, because it is taken to be

```
ls -l ha ha
```

Is there a way to make this work?  I think we could have made it

```
function ll {
    command ls -l "$@"
}
```

(note that `"$@"` is different from `"$*"`, with `"$@"` meaning individually quoted, while `"$*"` means all quoted in one string)

But then, `ll -t "ha ha"` would become `ls -l "-t" "ha ha"`, which actually works, but is kind of weird, and I am not sure if it may break down in some cases.

Is there another way to make it work, and another thing is, I think in the function, `command ls -l "$@"` and `ls -l "$@"` is the same?  (`command` is just to run the program directly and not call any possible bash function to prevent recursion from happening?)

Comment: `ll -t "ha ha"` is equal to `ls -l "-t" "ha ha"` in meaning, and `ll "-t" "-F" "ha ha"` is equal to `ls -t -F "ha ha"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the shell performs *quote removal* before it executes the `ls` there is no problem. You can safely use

```
function ll {
    command ls -l "$@"
}
```

and call it as `ll -t "ha ha"`. See your shell's manual page and search for "quote removal".

Comment: So is this `"$@"` a standard way of how people define alias using function?

Comment: You can use `"$@"` for this and any other purpose where it is important to keep whitespace as part of words (arguments). The handling of `"$@"`, i.e. a double quoted occurrence of `$@` is very different in this regard than `"$*"`.